# django: call function from views in template

Tags: django, function, templates, view

i have a function in `views.py` , for example something like this :

```
def get_base_content():
    footer = SiteContent.objects.get(pk=1)
    return {
        "footer" : footer,
}
```

how can i call this function in my `template` and use `footer` variable in it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have this variable shown on all templates, then you need to implement a [template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#the-django-template-language-for-python-programmers).

You just need minimal changes to your code:

```
def get_base_content(request):
    footer = SiteContent.objects.get(pk=1)
    return {"footer" : footer}
```

Now, add that to a separate file, call it `custom_context.py`. In your `settings.py` add it to your [`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) setting:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    "myapp.custom_context.get_base_content", # don't forget the comma!
)
```

Now, in your view code you just need to make sure you are using `RequestContext`. The easiest way to do that is to use the [`render` shortcut](http://django.me/render):

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def myview(request):
   return render(request,'hello.html',{'foo': 'bar'})
```

In `hello.html` you'll have `{{ foo }}` and `{{ footer }}`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a template tag, for your case, you may want to look at the [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags).